# how to add hours to my time

Tags: java, datetime

I have my time in the below format,

```
String from ="2015.08.31T16:00:00.000Z";
```

Is it possible to add eight hours to this time format?

Comment: Start by having a look at [Date Time Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and the [JavaDocs for the Date/Time API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a formatter using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");`
Then you can use ZonedDateTime.parse and ZonedDateTime.format.

Full code at [Online Java compiler IDE](https://www.codiva.io/p/0867b03f-f7de-419a-a0d8-85e8f71ab5bd)

Answer (score 0):

Write a parser, read the data, create a [date object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and the proceed to do with it whatever you like. No real shortcut that I know of, one way or another that string needs to be converted to time data.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in comments, the process has 3 stages:

```
String from ="2015.08.31T16:00:00.000Z";

//conver date string to Date
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
Date parsedDate = formatter.parse(from);
System.out.println(parsedDate);    // test output

//add 8 hours 
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(parsedDate);
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 8);
Date newTime = calendar.getTime();

//convert to original format
String to = formatter.format(newTime);
System.out.println(to);
```

Comment: This is using the old java date API. Use the new java 8 api or joda datetime api.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a non-standard date format, so you'll need a custom pattern:

```
DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
```

If you want to adjust the time, keeping the same zone offset (UTC +0, as indicated by the "Z" at the end), you can do this:

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTimeUTC = OffsetDateTime.parse("2015.08.31T16:00:00.000Z", pattern);
OffsetDateTime plus8hours = offsetDateTimeUTC.plusHours(8);
```

To get it back into String format you can use the same pattern like this:

```
String newTime = plus8hours.format(pattern);
```

which would be `"2015.09.01T00:00:00.000Z"`

If you wanted to make the adjustment to the zone offset instead of to the hours, you would do it this way:

```
OffsetDateTime plus8zones = offsetDateTimeUTC.withOffsetSameLocal(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-8))
```

If formatted in your format, it would be `"2015.08.31T16:00:00.000-08"`, which is the same instant in time, but with the zone offset adjusted rather than the local time.